# Convert <class 'bytes'> to string of '0' and '1' python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

How can I convert object of **class 'bytes'**

> b'\xd2\x9f\r'

To string of '0' and '1'

> 001011010110000010010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below

```
import sys
bin(int.from_bytes(b'\xd2\x9f\r', byteorder=sys.byteorder))
```

output
`0b11011001111111010010`

Answer (score 1):

In Micropython on ESP32 was the result:

```
>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b'-\x05\x05\xff',byteorder=sys.byteorder))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function doesn't take keyword arguments
```

Replacing the `byteorder` param with a default `0` did the job:

```
>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b'-\x05\x05\xff',0))
'0b101101000001010000010111111111'
```